# How Do I Performance Test My CorDapp?

Tags: corda

Most performance testing tools seem to be geared towards load testing web applications.

How do I load test a CorDapp?

Do I have to write an RPC Client to trigger flows or is there a Corda tool to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to wrap flow with an REST API in order to use state of the art tools. This also enables quick tests with Postman and alike.